# Error while configuring websphere in IntelliJ idea

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere

I have IntelliJ Idea v 10.5.4 ultimate edition, when trying to configure Websphere, this is the error I see and even if I give the right Websphere Home path, it does not proceed further. Can someone please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78275) in 10.5.3 and 10.5.4 versions. You can fix it by downloading the `webSphereIntegration.zip` file linked to the issue above and unpacking it over the broken version in `IDEA_HOME\plugins` directory.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I can configure the Websphere.